# How does the Sabre turret prioritize targets?

Tags: borderlands-2

What enemies does Axton's Sabre turret shoot at first?

Closest enemies? Enemies with the most/least health? Enemies that are hurting you/the turret most?

Comment: I think it is the enemy that you shoot, so the turret will assist you in whoever you are trying to kill.

Comment: I think the turret is acting like a derp shooting everything he wants randomly. I was shooting a monster and it was shooting Buzzard. Pretty dumb turret...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it's closest enemy first. Once locked on, it keeps tracking the enemy - doesn't matter how far he is from the turret.

So it goes like this: You launch the turret, it searches for the closest enemy and locks on it. (Even enemies have same AI and they will target the closest player. So if you throw your turret between you and the bad guys, they will target the turret instead of you.) The turret starts shooting the enemy until he/she/it is dead.

Comment: Is this from personal experience/testing or did you find a source somewhere? Would be useful to know either way!

Comment: @Alex its from my personal experience, and you can try it yourself. Maybe they use flood-fill or any other Nearest neighbor algorithm to find it out. Try throwing you turret in front of enemies and you will see it will start shooting nearest enemy and keeps shooting till he is dead. I never saw turret switching changing targets. (best way to confirm it to deploy your turret near raaks and you will see it will keep shooting same raak)